# Handle Named constructors with factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, php, object-oriented-design, constructors, static-methods

In my current project I'm refactoring the code to get a DBAL. I have a `class Entity` that is the base class for all classes that model a database table. So there are several classes that inherit from `Entity` like `Document`, `Article` and so on.

```
abstract class Entity {
    /** @var DatabaseRequest $dbReuest */
    protected $dbRequest;

    /** @var Login $login */
    protected $login;

    /* some methods like insert(), update(), JsonSerialize(), etc.

}
```

Since all these classes have the same constructor `__construct( DatabaseRequest $dbRequest, Login $login )` and I don't want to throw around those two paramenters, I also made this:

```
class EntityFactory {

  public function __construct( DatabaseRequest $dbRequest, Login $login )
  {
      $this->dbRequest = $dbRequest;
      $this->login = $login;
  }

  public function makeEntity( string $class )
  {

    if ( $this->extendsEntity( $class ) ) {

        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass( $class );
        $construct = $reflection->getConstructor();
        $params = $construct->getParameters();


        return new $class( clone $this->dbRequest, clone $this->login );
    }

    throw new APIException( "Class $class does not extend " . Entity::class, JsonResponse::DEBUG );
  }

}
```

You call the method like this: `$factory->makeEntity( Document::class )` and this will give you an object of that class.

This way a change in in the `Entity` constructor reduced the refactoring effort to a minimum. However, in class that extend `Entity`I also defined some methods for the relationships between their tables. E.g.:

```
class DocumentAddressee extends Entity {

    /* ... */

    public static function createFromCustomer( Address $address )
    {
        $self = new DocumentAddressee( clone $address->dbRequest, clone $address->login );

        /* transferring data from Address to $self */

        return $self;
    }

}
```

(According to [verraes.net](http://verraes.net/2014/06/named-constructors-in-php/) this is a legit use of static methods as named constructory ).

And methods like these happen quite some times (roughly 1-2 methods per foreign key in a table). Now I'd like to keep those methods, because I can easily access dependend data this way. But I'd also like to keep those constructors to the factory so I don't have to refactor all 100+ Entity-classes when the Entity construcor changes (this might happen if we'll decide to use a QueryBuilder in the future.

Is there already some kind of best practice to handle these methods? Should I propably handle those relationships within the factory or model those relationships in extra classes?

Comment: Why don't you go procedural instead of fighting OOP? I ask this because PHP you have both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you only use the factory to create these objects for consistency. So, in the factory you have something like:

```
class EntityFactory {

    public function __construct( DatabaseRequest $dbRequest, Login $login )
    {
        $this->dbRequest = $dbRequest;
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    public function create($className)
    {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($className);
        if ($reflection->implementsInterface(Initialisable::class)) {
            throw new APIException( "Please use createFromEntity() to create $className");
        }
        return new $class( clone $this->dbRequest, clone $this->login );
    };

    public function createFromEntity(Entity $entity, $className)
    {
        $newEntity = $this->create($className);
        return $newEntity->initWithEntity($entity);
    }
}
```

You might want to add `initWithEntity()` to `Entity` class, as basic implementation i.e.:

```
class Entity {

    public function initWithEntity(Entity $entity) {
        $this->dbRequest = clone $entity->dbRequest;
        $this->login = clone $entity->login;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And here's the `Initialisable` interface with updated `DocumentAdressee`.

```
interface Initialisable {
    public function initWithEntity(Entity $entity);
}

class DocumentAdressee implements Initialisable {
     // got initWithEntity() from parent class
}
```

With `initWithEntity()` there's no need to open access to `Entity` properties for `EntityFactory`, so no need to use reflection there. To create a `DocumentAdressee` object, you use:

```
$factory->createFromEntity($address, DocumentAdressee::class);
```

This should work for the problem in your question, where an Entity can have 1 to 1 relationship, e.g. the `DocumentAdressee`. For classes that have one to many relationship, you'd need to create something like `initWithEntities()` and pass array of `Entity`s into that.

As for best practice, there are ORMs that you can use or look at, e.g. Doctrine.

**edit**

I added `Initialisable` interface to allow check if the class being created needs to be initialised with an Entity.

Comment: Why does that EntityFactory have static methods?

Comment: @Tekay37 no particular reason, I edited the code to use your example

Comment: Ok, so one last question: This `init___()` are supposed to be the first method called on a freshly created object. Should this use of an init-method be enforced to render misuse impossible or would it be enough to document its purpose?

Comment: You can add check to see if init__() has been called in the classes that needs to be initialised. I don't think it's possible to enforce usage of init__() without adding constructor to all the classes that need it. I edited to add check in EntityFactory to make sure init__() will be called where it's needed.